# coredata is best?

Tags: iphone, ipad, core-data

coredata is better than FMDB?can we maintain primary key in core data? or any other method
to achive instead of using primarykey in core data?any tutorial please?

Comment: Core Data does not require primary keys because it is not an SQL database but rather an object graph management system. Each object instance is by definition unique and occupies a unique position within the graph that defines it as absolutely unique. If you try to think of Core Data in SQL terms you will come to grief.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think these two things are analagous.  FMDB is merely a wrapper around the native SQLite APIs, CoreData is an object persistence framework for which SQLite is one possible persistent storage type.

Check out the CoreData Programming Guide from Apple:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html

As well as this guide to developing with CoreData on the Mac:
https://developer.apple.com/macosx/coredata.html

CoreData does not offer primary key uniquing though, typically uniquing is handled by your application code.  FMDB, or even the native SQLite API's might be better for you depending on your specific requirements.

Comment: Uniquing in Core Data is handled by the object graph itself. Each object and each relationship are unique by definition.

Comment: Each instance of an NSManagedObject is uniqued, as CoreData will manage it's own primary key in the SQLite table.  However CoreData takes no steps to ensure the objects are actually distinct.  I.e. let's say you have some entity with a memberId, or emailAddress, you may want to unique based on one of those properties and there's no built-in facility in CoreData to do that.